# Querying Child Collections in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of objects called `Gigs`.

Each `Gig` has an `Acts` collection.

Using Linq I want to query my collection of gigs to get all gigs where with an act that has an id of 7 for example.

```
act.id = 7;
```

So I started writting...

```
return from gig in qry
       where gig.Acts //not sure how to do this bit
       select gig;
```

But I'm not sure how you set conditions on the child collection called acts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Essentially the same as Mike_G, only more verbose syntax and using equality.

```
var myCollection = from gig in qry
                   where gig.Acts.Any(act => act.ID == 7)
                   select gig;
```

Just an edit to bring comments to the answer:

Actually query is for an ID on a member (Artist) on the Act object that can be null.

new Query:

```
var myCollection = from gig in qry
                   where gig.Acts.Any(act => (null != act.Artist) && (act.Artist.ID == 7))
                   select gig;
```

Comment: Yours is actually a little off since Acts is a collections itself, that does not have a property of ID.

Comment: yes I realized that after I wrote it.. Derp, was just going to edit.

Comment: I completely forgot about Any!  I wonder which out of all the queries listed, which is the fastest.

Comment: I get this error when I try this: Member access 'Shared.DO.Artist Artist' of 'Shared.DO.Act' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shared.DO.Act]

Acts is a List<Act>

Any ideas?

Comment: Note... my actual request was:

from gig in qry
                   where gig.Acts.Any(act => act.Artist.ID == 7)
                   select gig;

Artist can be null!

How do I account for this??

Comment: Can you edit your post with a simple definition of the Gig and Act objects, it sounds like a member (Artist) on the Act object is inaccessible, but I can't really tell.

Comment: ahh okay,  ig.Acts.Any(act => (null != act.Artist) && (act.Artist.ID == 7))

Comment: I edited my question a moment ago to bring the actual answer into context.  It should work, please let me know.

Comment: So the full query is now:

    return from gig in qry
                   where gig.Acts.Any(act => (null != act.Artist) && (act.Artist.ID == artistId))
                   orderby gig.StartDate
                   select gig;

I still get the same exception when I call allItems.Count() on the data..

Comment: is allitems the variable you are setting to the return of your method call?  Try doing alltimes.ToList().Count and see if it is zero. It sounds odd that it would be the exact same exception unless the getter for Artist does something that can throw a nullreference

Comment: Calling IList<Gig> list = gigs.ToList(); (where gigs is the result) causes the same exception... 
IList<Gig> list = gigs.ToList();
Member access 'Shared.DO.Artist Artist' of 'Shared.DO.Act' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shared.DO.Act]

Comment: If I simplify the query to:
return from gig in qry where gig.Acts.Any(act => act.ID == actId)
orderby gig.StartDate
 select gig;

I get the exception:
Member access 'System.Guid ID' of 'Shared.DO.BaseDO' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shared.DO.Act]

Comment: Note: BaseDO is just a simple object with a Guid ID property

Comment: is the artist field setup as a reference to act through a datacontext/emf or are these custom POCOs?  I am not familiar with that particular exception and am having a problem figuring out exactly what would cause this.

Comment: I assume BaseDO is a base class, what is the modifier for the class and the ID property.. public?

Comment: Yep - its all public... I wonder if it could be to do withe intial LinqToSql request? Basically I have a linqToSql request which gets returned as an IQueryable<Gig>. I'm then filtering further using the linq statement that you've already seen. I'll post the linqToSql statement..

Comment: return from g in DBContext.Gigs
                   let acts = GetActs(g.ID)
                   select new Shared.DO.Gig
                   {
                       ID = g.ID,
                       Name = g.Name,
                       Acts = new List<Shared.DO.Act>(acts),
                   };

Comment: The GetActs just returns a collection of  IQueryable<Shared.DO.Act>

Comment: That might be the problem it must be breaking the entityreference when  for the Artist object on Acts when assigning acts to a new list on a new object of Gig.  well this may be suboptimal but try Acts = acts.ToList() instead of passing the queryable to the ctor of list.

Comment: I removed from the LinqToSql query the request for the acts data. So now every Gig object will have an unpopulated Acts collection. When I query the gigs collection the problem still occurs! So it seems its something to do with my object structure?? I post the object defs below

Comment: public class Gig : BaseDO
    {
        public IList<Act> Acts
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        #endregion
    }

Comment: public class BaseDO: IDO
    {

        #region IDO Members

        public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
}

Comment: public class Act : BaseDO
    {
        public Guid GigId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }

Comment: If I build the gigs collection manually - i.e. in code and not from the database, the query works fine. However, if grab it from the LinqToSQL the exception occurs, even if I'm not populating the acts collection in the LInqToSQl.

Comment: I've reasked this question with a bit more detail related to this bug here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524062/linqtosql-and-the-member-access-not-legal-on-type-exception

Answer (score 7):

```
var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.Select(a=>a.ID).Contains(7));
```

these two queries also return the same:

```
var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.Count(a=>a.ID == 7) > 0);

var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ID == 7) != null);
```

Comment: Linq is really, weird since there are a couple ways to write the same query.

Comment: So the full request is....

var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.Select(a=>a.Artist.ID).Contains(7));

If Artists is null (which is perfectly valid) I get an exception...

'Shared.DO.Artist Artist' of 'Shared.DO.Act' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shared.DO.Act]

Hmmm thoughts?

Comment: Just modify it too look at the artist first, before checking the ID:

var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.Select(a=>a.Artist).Select(b=>b.ID).Contains(7));

or

Comment: var x = gigs.Where(g=>g.Acts.Count(a=>a.Artist!=null && a.Artist.ID == 7) > 0);